# Having problem with Paramiko in Genymotion. Error: paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, paramiko

I'm having problem with the paramiko command as it gives me a bad authenication type. Played around with not having username and password.

I'm trying to run this command.
ssh -i ./keys/genymotion-key.pem shell@ec2-54-153-114-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 'su -c "setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb"

## SSH server details

```
ssh_host = 'ec2-54-153-114-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'
ssh_port = 22
ssh_username = 'shell'
ssh_password = "i-08ff55b9199f1e1ec"
ssh_private_key_path = './keys/genymotion-key.pem'

# Command to execute
command = 'su -c "setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb"'

# Read private key from file
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=ssh_private_key_path)

# Establish SSH connection
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect using the private key
ssh_client.connect(ssh_host, port=ssh_port, username=ssh_username, password=ssh_password, pkey=private_key)

# Execute the command
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)

# Print command output and errors
print("Command Output:")
print(stdout.read().decode())
print("Command Errors:")
print(stderr.read().decode())

# Close the SSH connection
ssh_client.close()
```

I've tried removing username, password, and keyfiles. The thing is that it says that "publickey" is not informative.  I'm wondering if I need to set my RSA key to public.

Comment: ssh -i ./keys/genymotion-key.pem shell@ec2-54-153-114-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 'su -c "setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb"

Comment: Why do you think the username should be "shell" ?

Comment: https://docs.genymotion.com/paas/Access/04_ADB/ has shell written in their guide.  You can scroll down to section enable adb

Comment: Can you authenticate with `ssh`? How? Using the command in your question? (your wording is confusing). Post its verbose output (`-vvv`). Why are you passing `password`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can run this command and authenticate. ssh -i ./keys/genymotion-key.pem shell@ec2-54-153-114-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 'su -c "setprop persist.sys.usb.config adb" –

Comment: And the output? And an answer to my question about `password`?

Comment: Hi Martin, the command doesn't output anything, but when I check the emulator, adb is enabled on the device. I was just testing a password that genymotion suggested.https://docs.genymotion.com/paas/02_Getting_Started/021_AWS/. . The password is the instance id.